# GridViewの列を固定してスクロールバーでスクロールしたい

Tags: c#, asp.net

asp.netのGridViewにて横スクロール時に固定表示する列とするクロールする列を分けて表示する方法を探しています。
検索してでてくるFreezingやFreezingColというキーワードでスタイルシートを使う方法は、Windows 10 の IE11では動作しないとのことで他の方法を探しています。

知見のある方どうかよろしくお願い致します。

jQueryは、最終手段のため利用しない方法を希望します。

Comment: ASP.NET＆IE11で使えるか不明ですが、こんな記事があります。[【WPF】【Toolkit DataGrid】超気持ちいいFrozenColumnCount](http://pro.art55.jp/?eid=982264) この中の`FrozenColumnCount`は今 [FixedColumnCount](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-datagrid-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid~Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Settings.DetailConfigurationSettings~FixedColumnCount.html) になっているかも。他関連 [Extended.Wpf.Toolkit 3.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/), [Extended WPF Toolkit - How to add reference to project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14809446/9014308), [DataGrid](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DataGrid)

Comment: 同様に使えるか不明ですが、こんな記事も。[GridViewの固定列対応](https://qiita.com/wonderful_panda/items/91035090fc1674dd90da) ここで言及されているStackOverflow記事はこちらでしょう。[Possible to Freeze Columns in a WPF ListView/GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3018588/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

「fixed_midashi.js」を使えば簡単にできます。IEもChromeもうまく動作します。

【注意点】
固定した列にasp.netのボタンがある場合、スクロールした状態でボタンを押してもasp.netのイベントが走りません。
そこで、ボタンが配置されているタグ（ボタン）にjavaScriptのクリックイベントを仕掛けてjavascriptから間接的にasp.netのイベントを呼び出します。

↓こんな感じで

```
<td style="text-align: center; color: black;" onclick="if(tdClick(this)==false){return false;}">
```

Answer (score 0):

すみません、検証していないですが、下記の方法で行けそうです。
https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/111780/How-to-freeze-GridView-column-and-row-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet/

Comment: URLのみの回答は[外部サイトへの単なるリンク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)として削除対象になりがちです。検証はしていなくても、方法を含めて記述するとより良い回答になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、jQueryは、使用しない方法が良いです。